# ¿De qué tipo de tipo de oración subordinada son "Sea lo que sea", "fuera lo que fuera", "haga lo que haga"?

Tags: subjuntivo, subordinadas

*Sea lo que sea, fuera lo que fuera, haga lo que haga*

¿Cómo se llaman las construcciones de este tipo? ¿Hay algún término gramatical?

Comment: No conozco propiamente la respuesta a tu pregunta, pero me parece destacable en este tipo de construcciones que empiecen y terminen con la misma palabra. Ese recurso retórico se llama **epanadiplosis**.

Comment: … muchas gracias, Rodrigo, sí ya sé, esto tiene q ver con la estilística... lo q yo necesito es saber si se trata de alguna frase relativa o algo x el estilo... gracias de todos modos : )

Comment: En realidad, esto no es epanadiplosis, o no originalmente. En estas construcciones, la última palabre es originalmente un futuro del subjuntivo (*sea lo que fuere*, *fuera lo que fuere*, *haga lo que hiciere*...), tiempo verbal que ha caído en desuso y ha acabado siendo sustituido.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se trata de una **estructura reduplicativa de subjuntivo**.

Leo en ["Prisma de ejercicios, Método de español para extranjeros"](https://books.google.nl/books?id=GQOFDlufPMoC&lpg=PA100&dq=construcciones%20reduplicativas&hl=es&pg=PA100#v=onepage&q=construcciones%20reduplicativas&f=false), nivel B2 avanza, por Azucena Encinas, Ana Hermoso y Alicia López (también el libro de nivel C1 tiene datos al respecto).

> *Estructuras reduplicativas de subjuntivo*
>
> Estas construcciones pertenecen al grupo de oraciones subordinadas
>   concesivas (es decir, aquellas que indican un contraste entre las dos
>   ideas expuestas), aunque esta vez se sustituyen los conectores por una
>   estructura repetitiva cuyos verbos siempre se encuentran en modo
>   subjuntivo.
>
> **Forma**: La estructura se forma mediante dos verbos exactamente iguales
>   en modo subjuntivo unidos por una preposición opcional y un pronombre
>   relativo.
>
> *Vayas a donde vayas, siempre te encontrarás a alguien conocido en esta ciudad.*
>
> **Uso**: Como se puede apreciar, la frase está formada por dos partes muy
>   bien diferenciadas y siempre separadas por una coma. Estas partes se
>   contrastan con el fin de señalar o informar que la parte B de la frase
>   va a llevarse a cabo con indiferencia al impedimento u objeción que se
>   plantea en la parte A.

Nótese que también hay quien lo nombra [construcción reduplicativa](http://www.udel.edu/leipzig/depende/subj_relativas.htm).

Comment: ... ¡genial! muchísimas gracias : )